# Lifecycle of static objects in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, lifecycle

In WP application I need to save authorization cookies between page navigation. But I am afraid that Garbage Collector can grab my `static System.net.CookieCollection` object while user navigates between app pages, or if user minimize app or something else.

Could somebody describe `static objects` lifecycle in Windows Phone?

I do not want to create database for cookies, but I need to save them for preventing reauthorization each time.

Comment: Tryed saving them in isolated storage?

Comment: Yep, I was thinking about it, but I got more that one cookie, and each cookie has many fields (name, value, domain, etc...), of course I can put all fields in one string like this: name=sdasd?value=asdasd and so on, but how I could store unknow count of different cookies in `IsolatedStorageSettings`?

Comment: Hmm, but I can store them in file, for example xml... I have to think about that

Comment: Can't you store it as a collection?

Comment: In `IsolatedStorage`? Theoretically I can serialize `CookieCollection` and save it as file, and then deserialize it... Thank you for advice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lifecycle of Static Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11394203/lifecycle-of-static-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use a Singleton to store your cookies. It's quite a different strategy from the `static` pattern but it may come in handy for you.

Take a look to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx if you want to go deeper about the singleton pattern. You can find an useful comparison between static classes and the singleton pattern at http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton-static.

Anyway, you must remember that the lifecycle of a `static` object and of a `singleton` it's exactly the same, and it's the same of their app domain. That means that their value is not lost until the app is terminated, either by the user or the operating system.

If you want to share the cookies between different *instances* of the app, i.e. if the app is closed (*by the user or by the OS when in background*), you have to save their value in the isolated storage. You can do it in `Application_Closing` and `Application_Deactivated`; the former is called when the app is closed, while the latter is called when the app is put in background.

Comment: I know about singleton pattern, but my question was about `static objects` lifecycle in WP apps. So how can I use singleton without fear that its value could be collected by GC?

Comment: Because if you don't dispose it yourself the GC won't do it. If the singleton value could be disposed by the GC any time, the entire design pattern would lose it sense! The singleton pattern has the same lifecycle of the application, and this is granted by its own design. But I'm afraid I'm missing a point here - you're afraid that GC takes away your static object, but you've never experienced it, right?

Comment: I am afraid, that GC can dispose `static objects` when user minimize app or something same. It is mobile app, its lifecycle is not same as desktop apps. When you tap home button, GC can release some memory, or may be not, that depends on free memory size, so that is why I am afraid of using `static objects`.

Comment: I didn't understand your question right; you don't have to worry about the lifecycle of your objects until your app is terminated. I edited my answer to match your clarification.